# Limit Socket io connections number

Tags: node.js, socket.io, connection, limit

Is it possible to limit socket io connections number in nodejs ?

I know one can configure limit by changing the server TCP settings, but I am looking for a way to do this in nodejs.

Comment: You could simply keep the number of connection in a variable which you would increase with every new connection and when it's over the limit you can close any new socket.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can implement it very easy:

```
var connectionsLimit = 1

io.on('connection', function (socket) {

  if (io.engine.clientsCount > connectionsLimit) {
    socket.emit('err', { message: 'reach the limit of connections' })
    socket.disconnect()
    console.log('Disconnected...')
    return
  }

})
```

Comment: hi, i was wondering - if i have socket.io on express server, do i need some kind of limiter on the express server as well?