# Socket.io - Limit max number of connections?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

Let's say I want only up to 100 users to join my server. Is there a way to do this internally?

Something like:

```
io.maxConnections = 100; //If client connections == 100, refuse next client connection
```

Comment: *Is there a way to do this internally?* no

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I would have to manually `socket.disconnect()` clients? Would seem like a problem if someone tried to **DDoS** my server

Comment: you can do it manually, see similar question1 [Limit Socket io connections number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35923014/limit-socket-io-connections-number) question 2 [Node JS how to limit maximum number of sockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52722540/node-js-how-to-limit-maximum-number-of-sockets) question 3 [How to limit my node.js client connections to 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19088253/how-to-limit-my-node-js-client-connections-to-2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @turivishal's answer, I found:

```
server.maxConnections = 100;//Max number of connections
```